# Should we avoid the use of "a" as a variable in Docs?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I ran into this in the [Python Language Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics), and one of my edits was [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/75111?draftId=62709) and the other [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/75156?draftId=62760). Particularly for the one that was accepted, both the initial rejecter and the accepter have a good bit of rep yet clearly did not agree. So if possible, I would like a consensus on the issue (and if it's not asking too much, clearly-written guidelines)...

Should we, in Documentation, avoid using `a` as a variable?
It's not inconceivable that someone, when quoting Documentation, can get the variable `a` confused with the word or letter a.

Now hold on, I know that sounds ridiculous at first glance! I myself was initially skeptical of this when I read it on an Edit proposal. After all, that's what code tags are for, so we don't confuse `this variable` with "this phrase". But beginner programmers, or those who aren't familiar with Markdown as used on Stack Exchange*, may not notice the distinction at first.

Add to that the occasional tendency to use quotes to indicate variables, the fact that comments (which are often used to quote code) are not formatted exactly as the rest of SO and can be difficult to read at times, and a few careless errors that we all can make occasionally: The possibility to confuse variables such as `a` with an English word, or vice versa, does exist.

Therefore I suggest that we use variables such as `x` that are already commonly used as variables and don't have a separate meaning as an English word. While the use of `a` may be unavoidable in certain circumstances, let's try and keep those occasions to a minimum.

As always, if you downvote please leave a comment (or answer) explaining why. ;)

*Yes, you could say "It's their own problem, they should just learn to read and use Markdown properly" but that doesn't really solve anything. Why not avoid the possibility for confusion in the first place?

Comment: Ideally, variable names should be descriptive (unless its canon to use a certain name). Unless you're storing coordinates, `x` is probably a poor choice also.

Comment: x can be confused with *, g with 9, o with 0, l with 1 or i, b with 8, s with 5 ...

Comment: @4castle I agree but using descriptive names would also increase the length of the examples. X can be confused with coordinates, that's a very good point.

Comment: @rene I would find it difficult to confuse `x` with * but I definitely agree on the others. ;)

Comment: foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz

Comment: If it matters, at first I thought that there might be a valid point here - that's why I approved the first edit. However, upon further consideration I agreed with the other reviewer that these edits add very little value for the noise. And really, the scenario where these variables would be problematic is a rather constructed one.

Comment: @WladimirPalant it does matter, and thanks for your comment. I was hoping you or another reviewer of my edit would reply. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both of those edits seem pretty pointless to me. If you're gonna do this, might as well use descriptive symbols. If you can't (or don't see the need) to do that, then replacing one arbitrary character with another is just a waste of time.

Note that in some cases, specific single-character variables have a long tradition of use and replacing them can be confusing (this is mostly going to involve formulas drawn from mathematics or engineering).

Comment: Exactly. Like in Java, most people name their `Pattern` object `p`, or their `Matcher` object `m`.

Answer (score 6):

No, banning a variable name doesn't sound like a good idea.

If the usage of a variable name isn't clear from the example or the context in which it is presented there are probably more issues to be solved then just some arbitrary coding-style rules.

In cases where the usage of  a single character variable name is not clear, maybe a comment can help.

If there needs to be a coding-style-guide/naming convention it might suggest to use descriptive variable names. That rules out the single letter ones, which helps in establishing good coding practices as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted Shog9's reply but yours definitely helped me see the problem from another perspective. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, those diamonds always get the good bits ...